# Won't go inside if statemente even when statemente is true. Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to make a simple calculator but the equals button doesn't perform as expected, it doesn't do any of the operations even though the if statement is true. This is the code

```kotlin
var value1: Float = 0f
var value2: Float = 0f
var operator: String = "n"

val input = expression.text.toString().trim()

//this is the adding button the subtracting, multiplying, and dividing are basically the exact code 
plus.setOnClickListener {
    if (input.isNullOrBlank()) {
        expression.text = ""
    } else {
        operator = "sum"
        value1 = expression.text.toString().toFloat()
        expression.text = ""
    }
}

//equals button
equals.setOnClickListener {
    val input2 = expression.text.toString().trim()

    if (!input2.isNullOrBlank()) {
        value2 = expression.text.toString().toFloat()

        // this is the textView and it always shows up as n
        expression.text = operator 

        //it never goes in any of these, I don't know if I'm setting it up wrong in the action buttons (add, sub, multi, div)
        if (operator == "sum") {
            var s = value1 + value2
            expression.text = s.toString()
            operator = "n"
        }    
        if (operator == "sub") {
            var r = value1 - value2
            expression.text = r.toString()
            operator = "n"
        }
        if (operator == "div") {
            var d = value1 / value2
            expression.text = d.toString()
            operator = "n"
        }
        if (operator == "multi") {
            var m = value1 * value2
            expression.text = m.toString()
            operator = "n"
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this happening? I don't know if I'm setting up the operator String wrong or if it's something else I'm doing wrong.

I wanted to have it so that if the values aren't imputed than the operator or equals button won't work like on the phone calculator

Comment: You have both `operator` and `operador` mixed up

Comment: @laalto the original variable is `operador` I tried to change them all to be in english, in the code it's all the same one

Comment: You say it always shows up as 'n'. So you can assume the value of operator is 'n'. In that case none of the if statements are true so it makes sense none are executed

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> val input = expression.text.toString().trim()
> ```

Here you capture the content of that edittext at view setup phase. It's likely empty at this point.

Then, in the click listener you have conditional code for that value:

> ```
> plus.setOnClickListener {
>     if (input.isNullOrBlank()) {
>         expression.text = ""
>     } else {
>         operator = "sum"
>         value1 = expression.text.toString().toFloat()
>         expression.text = ""
>     }
> }
> ```

and the `input.isNullOrBlank()` condition is always true so the else branch never gets executed.

You likely should read the input (`val input = expression.text.toString().trim()`) inside the click listener.

Comment: put one for each operator button? if I do that the app crashes as soon as I click the operator buttons

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with

```
//operator buttons
plus.setOnClickListener {
    if (expression.text.toString().trim().isNullOrBlank()) {
        expression.text = ""
    } else {
        value1 = expression.text.toString().toFloat()
        operador = "suma"
        expression.text = ""
    }
}
```

the equals button stays the same